# Invalid Argument using respond.js for IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using bootstrap.css file for responsive window. This is working fine in IE latest version. For IE8 support, i have added respond.js file. Using this script in IE8, I am getting "**invalide argument**" exception at **head.insertBefore(ss, lastLink.nextSibling);** of respond.js file. I can't find out the solution. Anyone face this issue and have solution means, please let me know.

Thanks,
Bharathi.

Comment: Do you have more than 31 stylesheets on your page? IE 8 has limits in number of [sheets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531194(v=vs.85).aspx) and [rules](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa358796(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1):

When using respond.js, we need host our sample in IIS server. Until it will throw the above mentioned error. I host my sample in localhost and checked. It is working fine now.